# Glyphicon icon not displayed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I use glyphicon icons in my project, I use bootstrap 3.0.0 .

I have problem to display `glyphicon-option-vertical` icon, it just not displaed!

Here how I use it:

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></span>
```

While all other icons displayed fine.Any idea why this specific icon is not displayed?

Comment: are you getting a square image instead or no image at all?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not declared in your Bootstrap CSS file. You might need to download the latest bootstrap from GitHub. Here you can find the fonts files
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/fonts